# at vs in vs to vs from in this sentence. Which to use?

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, american-english, writing

I am trying to convert the following news to a sentence to learn vocabulary words.

> Boris Nemtsov funeral: Russia restricts foreign mourners.

Which of the following sentences are correct?

> Russia restricts foreign mourners to Boris Nemtsov's funeral.
>
> Russia restricts foreign mourners at Boris Nemtsov's funeral.
>
> Russia restricts foreign mourners in Boris Nemtsov's funeral.
>
> Russia restricts foreign mourners from attending Boris Nemtsov's funeral.

They all seem to be correct. Which is the perfect sentence to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a closer look:

> Russia restricts foreign mourners **in** Boris Nemtsov's funeral.

Doesn't make sense. The only way to be **in** a funeral is being the dead person... and still this would be a really akward way of saying it.

> Russia restricts foreign mourners **at** Boris Nemtsov's funeral.

This would mean to hold them back, e.g. letting them only access certain areas. This may be a good transcript if the intended meaning is "restricts foreign mourners' presence" because the "at" would then refer to the occasion, not the group of people.

> Russia restricts foreign mourners **to** Boris Nemtsov's funeral.

Meaning foreign mourners may not go elsewhere, they are confined to the location of the funeral.

> Russia restricts foreign mourners **from** (attending) Boris Nemtsov's funeral.

This is  most likely the meaning of the original headline.

But keep in mind that we can not be absolutely sure because the information isn't there. When expanding a sentence we can only *assume*.

Comment: Stephie, that is an  excellent analysis and answer!